# Is it necessary to call `ssh-add` after login

Tags: ssh

I have my public key on the server, I have my personal key in *~/.ssh/identity*. If I execute `ssh-add` and enter my private passphrase, I can ssh without a password.

What I want is not to call `ssh-add` at all. I want to unlock the private key with the login to the system. I tried (maybe foolishly) import the identity file into the *seahorse*, but without any effect.

I don't want to have private key without a passphrase. I have Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

Comment: Use gnome-keyring (seahorse)

Comment: I found the problem --- it was because the public key did not have the same name. Once I ranamed files so that I had *.ssh/identity* and *.ssh/identity.pub* pair in .ssh folder, it was piece of cake :)